# How to prove the Generalised Binomial Theorem?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Reference: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Advanced_Calculus/Newton%27s_general_binomial_theorem.
${\displaystyle (x+1)^{r}=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\binom {r}{k}}x^{k}}$

At the end of the proof, the author says that the right hand side of the equation is $1$ when $x = 0$.

I think  $0^k = 0$, then why does the sum equal to $1$?

Comment: @Rohan I read the post. I was, however, wondering the proof of binomial theorem when r is not positive integer, so the link did not answer fully.

Comment: $0^0=1{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown Thanks!

Comment: To be frank the formula is $1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\binom{r}{k}x^{k}$ and the first term $1$ is also included in the sigma notation for index $k=0$ based on a convention that $x^{0}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Definitions such as 0!=1, 0^0=1, and  (r choose 0) =1 are conventionally applied to make sense of the first term in the summation.

Comment: And conventions such as 1!=1, x^1=x, (r choose 1)=r, etc. are conventionally applied to make sense of the subsequent terms.